# virtualenv python higer version

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, virtualenv

there' s a kinda old debian system (6.0.2) where the highest installed python version is 2.6 . I' ve an application requiring python 3.4 .

Is it possible to install python 3.4 into the virtual environment and to use that? I guess no, but i need some confirmation.

It' s not possible to install system- wide any python package.

Thanks.

Comment: Python 2 and 3 can coexist. But why not the latest Python3 version (currently 3.7) Do you really need exactly version 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install any python virtual environment. Just download that version of Python to your computer and create your virtual environment using it

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a new version of python first, and use that to create your virtualenv. You can either install manually (following the instructions on https://python.org), or use something like [Pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz). Pythonz can also be combined with [Pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew) to select python version when creating your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
The fastest way to achieve that is:

First, install python3 system-wide from repo.

`sudo apt-get install python3`
(If you need exactly python 3.4 then install exactly python 3.4)

Then install virtualenv

`sudo apt-get install virtualenv`

Check your python3 version with 
`python3 --version`
just to confirm that everything was fine with installation.

You should see something like this: `Python 3.6.7`.

Now you can create a virtual environment specifying the python version

`virtualenv -p python3.6 my_env`

This will create a my_env folder with your python3.6 environment in the current directory.

You can activate the environment with

`source my_env/bin/activate`

Hope it helps.